# getting dependency error angular 2 App

Tags: angular

```
{
    "name": "angular2-quickstart",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
        "lite": "lite-server",
        "postinstall": "typings install",
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
        "typings": "typings"
        },
        "license": "ISC",
        "dependencies": {
            "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
            "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
            "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
            "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
            "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
            "@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
            "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
            "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
            "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
            "font-awesome": "^4.6.1",
            "jquery": "^2.2.3",
            "lodash": "^4.13.1",
            "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
            "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
            "systemjs": "^0.19.29",
            "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
            },
            "devDependencies": {
                "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
                "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
                "typescript": "^1.8.10",
                "typings":"^1.0.4"
            }
        }
```

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package reflect-metadata does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.11 wants reflect-metadata@^0.1.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer angular2@2.0.0-beta.6 wants reflect-metadata@0.1.2

Comment: Have you already done a "npm update"? It looks like you have installed 0.1.3 version

Comment: Use [**this starter files**](https://github.com/aravindfz/firstAngular4App)

Answer (score 0):

Update to Node.JS v6.9+ and NPM v3.x, and update reflect-metadata to 0.1.3 as noted.

Answer (score 0):

The error you describe occurs, because although you installed the package angular2-in-memory-web-api, which specifies that it needs the a certain version of another package to function properly. While said package is already installed through your angular installation, it is not the version the package specified.

With `npm update` you can try to update all packages to their most current version, including the bad dependency.